# in python, how to manipulate namespace of an instance

Tags: python

The question is in context of unit testing.
I have created an instance of the class I am testing, and trying to test one of its methods. The method uses data it gets from different class defined in separate module. I am going to mock that module.
How I can access my instance's name space - I have to do it before running the method I am testing, to mock module which contain definition of the class my method is getting data from?

Comment: So basically you are asking how to get a class to use a mock instead of another thing from a separate module? That's the most basic use case of any mocking library out there. Do you have a specific example where these approaches fail?

Comment: I would like to avoid using mocking libraries. It should be possible to do it without it, I only hope it will not be very complicated.

Comment: You should absolutely use a mocking library. Doing it well requires an excessive amount of extremely fragile, complicated and delicate code. You *can* do a quick one-off monkey patch without too much trouble, but you'll have to repeat it everywhere (or you generalize it, at which point you have a shitty homemade mocking library), it'll be another cause for failure, it will make debugging harder, and you'll spend a lot of time fixing issues with that rather than with the code you're testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to create an example here which I think parallels what you are trying to do.

Say you have some class that we'll call `Data` that is defined in the module `foo`.  The `foo` module imports `bar` and a method of `foo.Data` calls `bar.get_data()` to populate itself.

You want to create a module `test` that will create an instance of `foo.Data`, but instead of using the actual module `bar` you want that instance to use a mocked version of this.

**You can set this up by importing `foo` from your test module, and then rebinding `foo.bar` to your mocked version of the module.**

Here is an example of how this might look:

- bar.py:

  ```
  def get_data():
      return 'bar'
  ```
- foo.py:

  ```
  import bar

  class Data(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.val = bar.get_data()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      d = Data()
      print d.val    # prints 'bar'
  ```
- test.py:

  ```
  import foo

  class bar_mock(object):
      @staticmethod
      def get_data():
          return 'test'

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      foo.bar = bar_mock
      d = foo.Data()
      print d.val    # prints 'test'
  ```

Although this will get you by for a simple test case, you are probably better off looking into a mocking library to handle this for you.

Comment: I have tried what you proposed myself, but was not careful enough. Now after analysing your example and looking carefully into the code I am testing it works! Thanks a lot!!